# Table structure for a conversation messaging system

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm looking to build a messaging system that handles conversation much like how Facebook does it. I'm wondering what the best way to do that would be in regards to table structure. Would I have one table like:

```
id
reply_id - the id of the original message that started the conversation
to_id
from_id
subject
content
date_sent
read_status
```

Or two tables:

```
table 1 - for the start of new messages

id
to_id
from_id
subject
content
date_sent
read_status

table 2 - when someone replies to a message

id
message_id
to_id
from_id
subject
content
date_sent
read_status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say one table. Why duplicate identical data? Besides, you will remove a source of error when your message data structure is altered by not having to care about the other table being identical to the first.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on a lot of things, but a first-guess attempt might be a self-referential table of "messages". For instance:

```
message:
  sender_id: User
  recipient_id: User
  in_reply_to_id: Message
  subject, content, etc
```

Message looks like:

```
  belongs_to :sender, :class => 'User'
  belongs_to :recipient, :class => 'User'
  has_many :replies, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :in_reply_to, :class => 'Message'
```

This would allow you to build up a tree of replies (because a message can be in_reply_to a message, which could in turn be in_reply_to yet another message). You may also want to consider using something like [acts_as_ordered_tree](http://ordered-tree.rubyforge.org/) for more flexibility and control.

Comment: I think this would be more along the lines of a Comments Table Structure, however still great for messages as well in some scenarios. +1

Answer (score -5):

The real best answer is:  MySQL is a exceedingly poor tool to build email and chat type systems.

Messaging system exist already.  Chat system exist already.  Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel?